# Using Bash, is it possible to get a list of files that were never read (or the modification time is the same as read time)?

Tags: bash

Say, if there is a folder, is it possible to get a list of all files in the folder and its subfolders, that were never read even once?

But is it possible? (because the "last access time" is actually updated when the file was written to).  If that is the case, then getting a list of all files where the last access time is the same as the last modification time will do too.

Answer (score 4):

The following `perl` script will find all files that have their atime <= mtime (ie. files which were not read since they were last written to), and print their full paths:

```
$ perl -MFile::Find=find -e 'find {
   wanted => sub {my @s=stat; print "$_\n" if $s[8]<=$s[9]},
   no_chdir => 1
}, @ARGV' files and dirs ...
```

Or, using unportable features of GNU find:

```
$ find [files and dirs ...] -printf '%A@ %T@  %p\n' |
  awk '$1 <= $2 { print substr($0, index($0, "  ")+2) }'
```

The `find` version is more precise, because it will also handle subsecond differences between the atime and mtime. It won't handle filenames which contain newlines -- that could be fixed by using `-printf '...\0'` and GNU awk (`gawk`) with `RS="\0"`; but then it will have to be decided on an output format where the embedded newlines will be distinctly shown.

You can either of them from `bash`; doing it in pure `bash` is left as an exercise to the reader ;-)

**Note about file timestamps:**

All this assumes that atime is actually working; that may not be the case if the file system is mounted with `MS_NOATIME`.

The atime is not updated when the file is just opened or written to, but only when it is read in one way or another (by read(2), pread(2), execve(2), etc).

Also, there is no "creation time" in unix; the ctime is the time of the status *change* and it will be updated any time its metadata is changed, or when the file is written to.

Recent linux kernels (> 4.11) also know about a creation/birth time of a file, accessible via the [statx(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/statx.2.html) interface. But that is non-standard and not supported yet in most distributions.